# Trying to reach an ArrayList outside of the class

Tags: java

So I'm currently working on an assignment where I'm supposed to create a Human class, which takes 2 arguments, an age and a name. Then I'm supposed to create a constructor which can random humen without taking any arguments, so I figured I just want to random a number and create a list of some sort with names, and then simply grabbing one of those names in there, my code is currently looking like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Humane31{
    int age;
    String name;
    public Humane31(int humanage, String humanname){
        age=humanage;
        name=humanname;

}
    public static  ArrayList<String> humaner=new ArrayList<String>();
}
    public Humane31(){
        this((int)Math.floor(Math.random()*10),humaner.get(0));
}

    public String getAge(){
        return "åldern är:"+age;
}
    public String getName(){
        return "namnet är:"+name;
}
    public String toString(){
        return "namnet är:"+name+"\n"+"åldern är:"+age;
}

    public static void main(String[] args){
}
}
```

I realize that my code is off and perhaps I shouldnt even use a hashmap for this, how can I fix this?

Comment: but what is the goal of the code you are writting? add and delete humans??

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but `ols.get(0)` isn't getting a random value (even if the map where in scope here).  It's always getting the first entry.

Comment: Currently the goal is to simply be able to random out humen without putting in any arguments, for example to get a human named "james", 47. The names I have to add to some sort of a list, but I dont understand how I'm supposed to make sure that my class "can see" the list.

Comment: In your latest edit, you've declared `humaner` outside of your class, which isn't legal in Java.  Move that line inside your class, next to `age` and `name`.

Comment: but if I move the arraylist inside the class, doesnt that mean I will have to at least have 1 human to reach the arraylist?

Comment: No, that's what the `static` keyword does.  It makes it defined at the *class* level, not per *instance*.

Comment: Also, now that your question doesn't involve hashmaps, you should probably [edit] your question title to make it more accurate.

Comment: just edited my code, still doesnt work, and when I put the arraylist under the public static main, it doesnt work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the goal is to make a Human class that can either (semi)randomly generate its private vars, or take them via a constructor, how about something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {

    //This is out Human class. I would suggest moving this outside of your Main class, but did it this way for simplicity's sake
    public static class Human {

        //This is our list of names we can choose from if we are not given one on construction. It uses Java's Arrays.asList to create the list, similar to using new ArrayList() followed by several .add statements
        private static final List<String> NAMES = Arrays.asList("Alex", "Billy", "Charlie", "Dan", "Eddie", "Fred", "Greg", "Harry", "Ian");

        //Our private class variables
        private final String name;
        private final int age;

        // No args constructor. This will generate a random number for an age(0-99), and randomly select one of our names by its index in the list by way of Java's Random class
        public Human(){
            Random random = new Random();
            this.age = random.nextInt(99);
            this.name = NAMES.get(random.nextInt(NAMES.size()));
        }

        //Arg constructor
        public Human(int age, String name){
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }

        //toString method, so we can print out the contents of our human
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Age: " + this.age + " Name: " + this.name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Random humans
        System.out.println(new Human());
        System.out.println(new Human());
        System.out.println(new Human());

        //Human with params
        System.out.println(new Human(1, "Joe"));
    }
}
```

Here's some sample output, but keep in mind the first 3 lines should change each run due to the randomness we introduced into the default constructor:

```
Age: 93 Name: Charlie
Age: 6 Name: Alex
Age: 73 Name: Eddie
Age: 1 Name: Joe
```

One of the key differences with this approach is that you no longer need to access the list of random names outside of your Human class. Instead, you can rely on the class to manage that internally.

**EDIT**
Sounds like you had some issues copying it over. Here's a live demo just incase - http://tpcg.io/nhmAqA

Comment: I'm trying to run it straight up, but it says "variable Arrays, class Human"

Comment: My bad, I didnt import the neccesary ultis, thanks a lot @Nick DeFazio ! I'll upvote you but I'm afraid it might not do much due to my account.